# For fibrations, is two out of three good enough?

Tags: homotopy-theory, fibration

Let $H_{X}\subset H_{Y} \subset H_{K}$ be closed subgroups of a topological group $G$. Let $X = G/H_{X}$ $Y = G/H_{Y}$, $K = G/H_{K}$. Now, suppose we have the following diagram:
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
X @>{\phi}>> Y\\
@ViVV  @VVjV\\
K @>{Id}>> K 
\end{CD}$$
Where $i$ and $j$ are both locally trivial fiber bundles and $\phi$ is equivarient w.r.t. the action of $G$. Does $\phi$ have the homotopy lifting property?

I have shown that given a homotopy $H:W\times I \rightarrow Y$ that there exist a map $\tilde{H}:W\times I \rightarrow X$ such that $H$ is homotopic to $\phi\circ \tilde{H}$ relative to $W\times {0}$. I wanted to know if this is good enough for the LES of homotopy groups?

Comment: Is $K$ abitrary? Because if yes, any taking $K$ to be a single point, any map from $X$ to $Y$ would make this diagram commute.

Comment: @HelloDarkness, No, X,Y and K are all related. X \subset Y \subset K as subgroups and the arrows are induced maps of between left cosets.

Comment: @HelloDarkness I updated the question.